# Resolve template_map within view (ZF2)

Tags: zend-framework2

So I have `$config['view_manager']['template_map']` with a bunch of keys being mapped to different files. I would like to resolve a key I have to its matching filename.
And I would like to do this within my view.

Comment: What EXACTLY do you want to do. Ultimately, you can just pass the config-array to your view and then do your stuff, but as of now whatever you're trying to do sounds "fishy" for doing it in the VIEW.

Comment: I want to include (not render) another template file where I ob capture HTML, save it to a variable and expect to access that variable within the parent template. Since in Zend Framework 2 you have template maps, I need some way to assemble the actual template file for including with the help of the template key.
This may sound a bit hacky, but it's actually the nicest way of doing what I need.

Comment: Well, write a simple viewHelper and inject the config into it ;) http://blog.evan.pro/creating-a-simple-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2 and `$serviceLocator->get('config')`